# Move social bar to the left on hover

Tags: css, animation, transform, transition

I would like to have a social bar on the right, and scrolling with the page. This is ok, but I would like to add some behaviors: If you hover the facebook logo, the logo moves to the left, and shows the like button. And same behavior for twitter. I already made a jsfiddle, so here's the link: [Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/Retiixx/vveosbf9/).

In the fiddle, at the moment my whole bar moves to the left, but I want the social buttons moving individually.

I am fine with JavaScript/jQuery, if necessary.

Here's my CSS and HTML code:

```css
.off-canvas-buttons{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    top:10%;
    height:auto;
    right:55px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    position:fixed;
    line-height:50px;
    transition:transform 1s ease;
}
.off-canvas-buttons > *, .off-canvas-buttons > * > *{
    height:50px;
    border:1px dashed red
}
.off-canvas-buttons:hover{
    transform:translate(-55px);
}
.backtotop{
    width:45px;
}
.facebook-logo, .twitter-logo{
    background-color:rgba(200,0,0,0.5);
    width:45px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="off-canvas-buttons">
    <div class="facebook">
        <div class="facebook-logo">FB</div>
        <div class="facebook-like">Like</div>
    </div>
    <div class="twitter">
        <div class="twitter-logo">Twi</div>
        <div class="twitter-follow">Follow</div>
    </div>
    <div class="backtotop">▲</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found what I wanted to (it was a CSS rule problem). Here is the updated fiddle: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Retiixx/vveosbf9/4/)

Here is the code:

```css
.cover {
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 110px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
}
.off-canvas-buttons {
  top: 10%;
  height: auto;
  right: 55px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.off-canvas-buttons > * {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.social {
  transition: transform 2s ease;
}
.off-canvas-buttons > .social:hover {
  transform: translate(-55px);
}
.off-canvas-buttons > .social:hover >:first-child {} .backtotop {
  width: 45px;
}
.facebook-logo,
.twitter-logo {
  width: 45px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
  <div>
    <div class="off-canvas-buttons">
      <div class="facebook social">
        <div class="facebook-logo logo">F</div>
        <div class="facebook-like action">L</div>
      </div>
      <div class="twitter social">
        <div class="twitter-logo logo">T</div>
        <div class="twitter-follow action">S</div>
      </div>
      <div class="backtotop">▲</div>
    </div>
```